# WCF with legacy clients

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, tibco

I have been asked to replace a legacy "service" which processes XML requests (of an arbitrary format with no schema...) from multiple clients (Excel macros, C# apps) over Tibco EMS. I have no control over the clients.

I was hoping I could use WCF for this task but I don't think I can without a service contract. I have been toying with the idea of creating a WCF service and another console app service which would intercept and parse the existing XML requests and forward to the new WCF service (which new clients would use and existing clients could eventually migrate to).

However, this is adding complexity which could become a support and development headache. As such, I am tempted to build a console app based service which feels like a shame seeing as how much you get for free with WCF.

Has anyone else developed WCF apps for legacy non-REST, non-SOAP clients?

Comment: What does _"I don't think I can without a service contract"_ mean exactly? How do the clients send the XML, and what response do they expect? Have you thought of a custom binding?

Comment: Good questions! Apologies for the lack of clarity. My issue is that the clients send and receive a propriety/arbitrary XML format and I don't understand how/if I can make a WCF service interface. The clients do this over an EMS queue. There is a WCF EMS library so that is less of a problem for me than attempting to define a service contract for the arbitrary XML format.

Comment: Well, unless all you do is storing the XML you get with no processing (or forwarding it), you need a schema. It may not be formalized as XML schema, but it must be documented. Otherwise processing the data will be kind of hard. And that - in code - looks like a service contract. Processing requires a known schema.

Comment: @TomTom Its worse than you think. The original implementation reads the first element of the XML and then performs highly customised parsing based on that. The code parsing the XML is basically the XML documentation as far as I can tell. There is also some lovely handcoded XML in there as well.

Comment: I think what you are saying is "Get or create a schema and theres your service contract". That seems sensible although I will probably need to look at custom bindings as suggested by @CodeCaster to see how WCF can read raw XML.